# Move focus from one ImageButton to another

Tags: android, android-layout

I am fairly new to android and stuck on one problem. I need to know how I can response when I use directional keys on android ImageButton. I have been looking for the answer for almost a day now and can't find one.
    What I need to achieve is I want to change focus to ImageButton4 from ImageButton3 if/when I click the right arrow key.
    I know android handles this on its own but I need to customize it for my application.
    I tried implementing OnKeyListener

```
private OnKeyListener speedTest = new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface inter, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

    }
        return false;
    }
};
```

But I'm not sure if this would be the best way to do it since with each click I have to check where is focus and then change it accordingly.
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried keyCode == KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT?

Comment: Well like I said I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. Since checking each time which ImageButton is focused (I have to move focus from each button differently).

Comment: you can also define the focus order in xml using android:nextFocusRight/Left/Down/Up (android:nextFocusRight="@+id/image_button_to_focus_on_right")

Comment: Eureka! That solves the problem. I was using (android:nextFocusRight="@id/image_button_to_focus_on_right"). Thanks